# Storing the order of vertices in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I tried storing my graph data in R as:

```
g<- graph.formula(1-2,1-3,2-3,2-4,2-7,3-4,3-6,3-7,3-8,3-9,3-10,4-8,4-9,5-6,5-7,5-8,6-7,6-8,6-9,6-10,7-8,7-9,8-9,8-10)
```

using the igraph package in R.

However, upon looking at the order of the vertices:

```
V(g)$name
```

It returns:

```
 "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "7"  "6"  "8"  "9"  "10" "5"
```

May I know how would I need to input the data so that it appears in an ascending form?

Comment: If you want it in ascending order, sort it. What's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what your reason behind this is, but here are two options:

---

Option 1: reorder your formula while creating your graph:

```
g1<- graph.formula(1-2,1-3,2-3,2-4,5-6,7-8,8-9,8-10,2-7,3-4,3-6,3-7,3-8,3-9,3-10,4-8,4-9,5-7,5-8,6-7,6-8,6-9,6-10,7-9)
V(g1)$name
```

---

Option 2: Extract the edgelist and create a new graph with that:

```
# get.edgelist(g1) returns the structure below.
edges <- structure(c("1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
            "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", 
            "8", "2", "3", "3", "4", "7", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
            "8", "9", "6", "7", "8", "7", "8", "9", "10", "8", "9", "9", 
            "10"), .Dim = c(24L, 2L))
g2 <- graph(edges=edges)
V(g2)$name
```

Both output:

```
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
```

Comment: another option: `permute(g, match(V(g)$name, 1:10))`